# Android: There are some standard system PIDs in Android?

Tags: android, pid

I implement an app with some list of process IDs. I used `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ps")` to became this list. But I don´t need all processes like `PID 1 --> init`. There are some max. PID value for this standard PIDs ? Can I just filter them by using something like `if PID > 1000 , then use it`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only guaranteed PID is that of `init` which is `1`. The other processes that start up early will usually get a PID in the same (short) range just because they're started mostly in the same order every time, but you can't really rely on that.

You'll need to filter yourself, a pure numeric filter will not work all the time. (PIDs can get recycled too, so it is entirely possible to get a normal, user process with a very low PID.)

Comment: Thanks. One more question for better understanding of it. Are UIDs unique? If f.e. UID from Google Talk (com.google.android.talk) is 10034 , so it is 10034 of all android devices?

Comment: I have no idea about that. You should post another question if you can't find an answer to that.